# expand code folds recursively

Tags: php, netbeans

When I collapse all folds (default is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>) and then expand the function I'm working on (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>), it leaves any smaller segments (within `{...}`) collapsed.

Is there a way to expand a fold AND any folds contained within that fold?

If not, is it posible to at least select which types of code get folded? (e.g. never collapse for loops and `if..else` statements)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to expand a fold AND any folds contained within that fold?

By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> should unfold recursively

Comment: That expands everything. Is there any way to just expand one function but also expand everything within that function? For example, if I have 3 functions (A,B,C) and B has two for-loops (a,b) inside of it. From having everything collapsed, I want a command to expand `B` and subsequently `a` and `b` since they are within the parent fold.